# Convert an integer into a signed string in Ruby

Tags: ruby, integer

I have a report in which I'm listing total values and then changes in parentheses. E.g.:

**Songs: 45 (+10 from last week)**

So I want to print the integer 10 as "+10" and -10 as "-10"

Right now I'm doing

```
(song_change >= 0 ? '+' : '') + song_change.to_s
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
"%+d" % song_change
```

[String#%](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ref_c_string.html#String._pc) formats the right-hand-side according to the print specifiers in the string.  The print specifier "%d" means decimal aka. integer, and the "+" added to the print specifier forces the appropriate sign to always be printed.

You can find more about print specifiers in [Kernel#sprintf](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ref_m_kernel.html#Kernel.sprintf), or in the [man page for sprinf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf).

You can format more than one thing at once by passing in an array:

```
song_count = 45
song_change = 10
puts "Songs: %d (%+d from last week)" % [song_count, song_change]
# => Songs: 45 (+10 from last week)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a method to Fixnum called to_signed_s, but that may be overkill. You would eliminate copying and pasting, however, which would be good.

Personall, I'd just write a StringUtil class to handle the conversion.

Alternatively, a better OO solution would be to wrap the FixNum in a holder class and override THAT class's to_s.

IE: Create a class called SignedFixnum and wrap your Fixnum objects in it whenever they need to be signed.

Comment: I like the idea of a new class.  Maybe that seems like overkill, but for all we know there could be a bunch of other functionality that could go in there.  Or maybe there isn't yet but there will be later.

Comment: This is pretty straightforward Decorator pattern, I think. For small projects it's overkill, but if this is to be reused much, it could net big gains.

Answer (score 1):

Wayne already posted what I consider the best option, but here's another one just for fun...

```
"#{'+' if song_change >= 0}#{song_change}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your original code is good, just extract it out into a helper so it doesn't clutter up your views and you don't have to repeat it each time that you want to use it.

Put it in your application_helper.rb file like this

```
  def display_song_change
    (song_change >= 0 ? '+' : '') + song_change.to_s
  end
```